# How do I use Django's built in password reset function?

Tags: django, passwords, reset

I am using the following code to use Django's built in password reset functions. Everything seems to work for some email addresses but not for others. I know for sure that I am having difficulties with @btopenworld.com addresses. I have read other places saying that the user accounts need to have functional passwords set up. I have tried the same user account with different passwords (some reset emails get delivered, some do not). Any ideas on how to get this working more consistently?

```
In my login template file:
<div class="mt-4">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center login_container">
<a href ="{% url 'reset_password' %}" class="btn btn-warning" >Create / Reset Password</a>

In my urls.py file:
path('reset_password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="accounts/password_reset.html"), name="reset_password"),

In the password_reset.html file:
<p>Enter the email address used to create your account, and we’ll email instructions for setting a new password.</p>

<form method="post">

{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<input type="Submit" name="Send email">
</form>
```

Comment: If some emails are getting through, the problem likely isn't with your django code, but with how your emails are being sent (eg, the from: address may be being judged as untrustworthy).  Are you getting any bouncebacks in the sending account?

Comment: Hi, no bounce backs. When I send other emails via views.py functions, to the @btopenworld.com address they get through ok. It's just the password reset one that doesn't. I have had other uses complain that they are not receiving the reset emails.